Error: Main parameters are required ("file1 [file2 file3...]")

All my prog is getting same error previously it was running well
Error: Main parameters are required ("file1 [file2 file3...]")
Usage: <main class> [options] file1 [file2 file3...]
  Options:
    -d
      The directory where the file(s) will be created
      Default: .

Getting this error while running the code in java selenium. Previously all the application was running fine suddenly within 40 prog only 2-3 are running well, rest i am getting same error.
I have no clue suddenly what happened, I updated my system and installed TestNG from that day i am getting this error.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
